# file_get_html(); not working with Teleduino links

Tags: php, html, get, arduino, simple-html-dom

I am making a home automantion project with Arduino and I am using [Teleduino](https://www.teleduino.org/) to remotely control an LED as a test. 
I want to take the contents of [this link](http://us01.proxy.teleduino.org/api/1.0/2560.php?k=202A57E66167ADBDC55A931D3144BE37&r=definePinMode&pin=7&mode=1) and display them into a php page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

include 'simple_html_dom.php';

echo file_get_html('http://us01.proxy.teleduino.org/api/1.0/2560.php?k=202A57E66167ADBDC55A931D3144BE37&r=definePinMode&pin=7&mode=1');

?>

</body>
```

The problem is that the function does not return anything.

Is something wrong with my code?
Is there any other function I can use to send a request to a page and get that page in return?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Your URL retrieve HTML (test it in browser)? I do not think so.

Comment: @AbraCadaver how would that be useful?

Comment: @fusion3k There is no html in the page I am retrieving the data from, it is just a string of text not delimited by tags. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Read the API documentation. it is JSON, so you have to use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you had to use function file_get_contents but your server is protcting data from scraping so curl would be a better solution:

```
<?php 

// echo file_get_contents('http://us01.proxy.teleduino.org/api/1.0/2560php?k=202A57E66167ADBDC55A931D3144BE37&r=definePinMode&pin=7&mode=1');

                      // create curl resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://us01.proxy.teleduino.org/api/1.0/2560.php?k=202A57E66167ADBDC55A931D3144BE37&r=definePinMode&pin=7&mode=1");

    //return the transfer as a string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

    // $output contains the output string
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    echo $output;

    // close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: All right, I am trying this out and it is working. Thank you! I will look into allowing the file_get_content function to work if you say it is better

Comment: I am not saying that is it better :) curl is perfectly fine for that, it emulates the browser so your webserver thinks that the visit comes from a real browser :) You're welcome